# Connecting to Oracle DB on Oracle Developer Days vm in mac os x

Tags: macos, oracle11g, virtualbox

I am new in this world, and I have been learning oracle database.
I have installed the Oracle Developer Days vm on mac os x,
and it works well.

but I want to work with database in vm locally on mac(not in vm).

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Barry McGillin has an [excellent writeup](http://barrymcgillin.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-oracle-developer-days-virtualbox.html) on how to do just that.

Comment: Please can you include a synopsis of the content of the blog post for reference, link only answers are usually frowned upon in case the link becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you succeed in vm installation then you can connect internal vm from host mac. So run the sql developer or any other oracle client in mac host machine and connect the oracle database by providing db-host-ip as vm ip address. 
Following link help you to understand how to connect oracle database in vm from host PC. 
http://praitheesh.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/oracle-developer-day-vm-how-to-use-pre.html